# What do you call if: -> { status_change? && finished? } in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am newbie in ruby.
In a ruby_on_rails project, I find below code in a rb file in models

```
...    
before_validation :start_at, if: -> { status_change? && finished? }
...
```

I don't understand the syntax used here... Can you tell what `if:` and `->` mean here?

Thanks

Comment: It’s a [keyword argument](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments) passed to `before_validation`. The argument value is a [proc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Procs) or lambda.

Comment: `if:` denotes the symbol `:if`. If you have a Hash where the keys are symbol, you can write it as either `{:foo => 46, :bar => 16}`, or, more fashionable, `{foo: 46, bar: 16}`. The `->` denotes a lambda, i.e. a Proc with checking the number of parameters. If someone would invoke it and, by mistake, pass a parameter, you would get a RuntimeError.

Comment: @Stefan not technically a keyword argument since the signature for the method does not define it as one [`def before_validation(*args, &block)`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/Callbacks/ClassMethods/before_validation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wow, there's a lot in your question...

Ruby allows you to put single line `if` statements at the end of a line. The preceding statement is only executed if the `if` statement returns true. These are often used for "[guard clauses](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/GuardClause)". But that's not exactly what's happening here...

Ruby also lets you drop the parentheses around method calls if it can infer exactly what the parameters are. Instead of typing `sum(a, b)` you can type `sum a, b`. It's one of the things that makes Ruby great for writing "Domain Specific Languages" like Rake and parts of ActiveRecord. Thoughtbot has a [good article](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/writing-a-domain-specific-language-in-ruby) on them.

Because of this, that line could be rewritten:

```
before_validation(:start_at, if: -> { status_change? && finished? })
```

In this case, before_validation is an [ActiveRecord callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html). From that link, "Callbacks are methods that get called at certain moments of an object's life cycle. With callbacks it is possible to write code that will run whenever an Active Record object is created, saved, updated, deleted, validated, or loaded from the database."

In this case what you have is a "[conditional callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks)". The `start_at` method (which you'll probably find defined at the bottom of the model file, or perhaps somewhere else, search the codebase for "def start_at") only gets called if the condition passes.

Regarding the condition itself, `status_change?` and `finished?` are also both methods. The question mark at the end is a Ruby convention to say this method returns a boolean. The `&&` is Boolean logic to say that the whole conditional will return true if and only if both `status_change?` and `finished?` return true.

So, to state what this line of code does in plain English:

- Before ActivRecord checks to see if the model is valid
- run the `start_at` method...
- ...but only if the `status_change?` method and `finished?` method both evaluate to true

Under the covers, the way this works is by passing a "lambda" as a parameter to the method. In this case it's using the "stabby lambda" syntax introduced back in Ruby 1.9. Check out [The Ultimate Guide to Blocks, Procs and Lambdas](https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/02/ruby-procs-and-lambdas/) and [Using Lambdas in Ruby](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/using-lambdas-in-ruby/) for more information.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the condition has to be passed to the class method as a proc so it can be evaluated in context of the instance upon validation. (which wouldn't be possible with a modifier-if)